# Roblox part not colliding correctly when using a spinning block script

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

My problem is currently beyond my knowledge and I don't know how to fix it. Here is my code for the spinning part.

```
while true do
   script.Parent.CFrame = script.Parent.CFrame * CFrame.fromRulerAnglesXYZ(0.1,0.1,0.1)
end
```

The code works perfect, but the block does not collide with the players how it should. Any idea how to fix this?

PS: I am using a custom StarterCharacter, but it collides with everything else just fine if that helps.

Comment: this is an infinite loop. is it run in a separate thread? otherwise nothing else will happen and your program will freeze. also there is no function as `CFrame.fromRulerAngles`. you mean `fromEulerAngles`.

Comment: adding a `wait(0.1)` into the loop will allow the thread to yield and your block should update.
As for collisions, is the block set to `CanCollide = true` ?

Comment: @Kylaaa Yes, the 'CanCollide' is set to true.